# Zend Framework 2 URL seems to ignore optional [/] when generating URLs?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a route like in my `module.config.php`  that looks like

`'route'    => '/service-form/key[/][:id][/][:step]',`

Despite the / being wrapped in brackets, using `$this->url()` returns a URL like 
`/service-form/key//` with two ending slashes. Why is this? I was under the impression that brackets made part of the route optional. Is that not the case?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead

```
'route'    => '/service-form/key[/:id][/:step]',
```

See [ZF2 Routing](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment) for more details